# Как сделать нумерацию строк как в видео NEOVIM

Tags: linux, vim

Каким образом можно сделать нумерацию строк в neovim (использую vundle), как у чувака на видео? Желательно(если можно) что бы рядом выводилась реальная нумерация строк(будет 2 полосы с цифрами) [Видео](https://youtu.be/MJXHosm4oJQ?t=93)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это фича вима и доступна без плагинов. Включается через "esc :" и команду `set relativenumber`. Ее можно и в vimrc вбить. Выключить можно через `set norelativenumber`. А вот одновременно и номера и "относительные номера" - такого я не знаю.

Comment: И на этом большое спасибо